# Laravel 7 Passport Api Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-validation, laravel-api

I created a Laravel login passport API but when email is provided "null" or password is null, it's not showing validation required error. It's returning html of something?

Here is my code of controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use\App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;



class AuthController extends Controller
{
   public function login(Request $request)
   {
      $loginData= $request->validate([
           'email'=>'required',
           'password'=>'required',
       ]);
      
       if(!auth()->attempt($loginData))
       {
           return response()->json(['message'=>'Invalid credientails']);
       }
       $accessToken =auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
       return response()->json(['user'=>auth()->user(),'access_Token'=>$accessToken]); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this

#### Also please make sure you include the class validator in controller-> use Validator;

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
       'email'=>'required',
       'password'=>'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
    { 
        $message = $validator->errors()->first();
        return response()->json(['statusCode'=>200,'success'=>false,'message'=>$message], 200);            
    }
```

Comment: Note: when hitting login api or any api make sure to add Content-Type:application/json in request.